# LCD screen: can this problem be caused by the inverter?

Tags: inverter, lcd, laptop, monitor, pixels

I'm repairing a HP 530 laptop with bad screen image. The image does not flicker, the corruption pattern is static.

If I connect an external monitor through the VGA port the image is fine, therefore I rule out the motherboard/GPU and I'm left with three components as the only suspects:

- Flat cable
- LCD inverter
- LCD panel

Do you think I can rule out the inverter too? If I understand correctly what it does, if it fails I get no image at all, therefore a kind of on/off failure type.

I would rule out the flat cable too, I replaced it a million times on another laptop and it also causes a blank screen issue. Moreover, flat cable problems cause intermittent failure which depends on LCD hinge position too.

I could replace the inverter first and see what happens (it's cheaper than the screen) but I don't want to waste money if you can explain me how such failure cannot be caused by the inverter

Thank you

[image: problem]

[image: inverter]

Comment: I don't think it's the inverter - but maybe get an o-scope on the output to check it isn't producing a stupid waveform that is somehow synced up to the lines on the screen.

Comment: I too do not think it is the inverter. It's the controller or cable that causes every second line to go out.

Comment: I would rule out the inverter because of the way the image looks. This is a pixel-processing issue, so I would look at the chain of signal transmission. Try to squeeze the edges of the screen (carefully) or squeeze and move signal cable(s) to see if there is any change. There is a break somewhere on at least one signal line, but I cannot tell where for sure. It looks like a crack or break on the edge of the screen, possibly the ribbon disconnected from the screen in 1 or 2 spots.

Comment: Just because the VGA port works, doesn't mean there isn't something wrong on the LCD controller side. VGA and LCD are two very different protocols, they require specialized circuitry that may be bad for one, but OK for the other.

Comment: @EdinFifić thank you, it makes sense to replace the ribbon first. After all it's the most stressed component in the chain.

Comment: @Andyaka I only have a logic analyzer (not suitable for high voltages) and I'm quarantined, I can't check the output of the inverter.

Comment: @RonBeyer then I can only replace the ribbon first, see if it gets better, then the LCD screen (maybe an used one to mitigate risk) and if that fails too, new motherboard.

Comment: This is a very old computer, is it worth the effort?

Comment: I believe it's worth saving. With less than 100€ in new parts (including 4GB RAM, 250GB SSD, T7200 CPU) it can outperform any entry-level 300€ machine.

Comment: @EdinFifić I'm trying to squeeze and move the cable and the screen but nothing changes. There is some circuitry on the back of the screen too, maybe that's where the issue is

Comment: Yes, LCD screens have heat-bonded ribbons on them. Horizontal or vertical lines on screen during operation often indicate that some of those bonds have broken. If you press and move with your finger along the edge where they connect to the glass surface, you may come to the disconnected point and the lines on the screen would disappear as you temporarily make the connection. That is the location of the problem if it shows up like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is the LCD panel.

I bought an external controller model M.NT68676.2 that includes its own inverter and flat cable. I fed it the signal from a RaspberryPi and As you can see from the picture, the screen is corrupted the same way it looked when connected to the computer's motherboard.

[image]

And here's a picture of the setup, hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is flat cable.
Today, resolutions 1600x900 and 19200x1080 use odd and even lines. Оne of lines (odd or even) is broken. Some of other lines broken partially. Try to wrinkle the cable slightly. If image changing - it is а cable. Once I repared cable three times for good image.

Check the cable with a multimeter. Check RXEC+ (even clock plus)  RXOC- RXEC+ RXEC- first (may be LCD have signs). When one clock pair is damage - picture in thin stripes. (1st line is even, 2st line is odd 3th line even etc) If check 8 RXЕ-lines and 8 RXO-lines is ok - then it's LCD panel.

The LCD inverter is OK. The damage to the inverter looks different than here.